# How might I add JavaScript to tagged HTML text?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am trying to create what I think the worst website in the world would look like.
I want to add some JavaScript to a bit of text with the  tag. I've tried a few things to fix it myself, but I haven't been able to work this out. How can I make it work?

(The script is supposed to make the text rainbow colored, btw)
The script, with my text included:

```
var text= <marquee>"hello and welcoem to my website"</marquee> // YOUR TEXT
var speed=80 // SPEED OF FADE

// ********** LEAVE THE NEXT BIT ALONE!
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('marquee')[0];
if (document.all||document.getElementById){
document.write('<span id="highlight">' + text + '</span>')
var storetext=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("highlight") : document.all.highlight
}
else
document.write(text)
var hex=new Array("00","14","28","3C","50","64","78","8C","A0","B4","C8","DC","F0")
var r=1
var g=1
var b=1
var seq=1
function changetext(){
rainbow="#"+hex[r]+hex[g]+hex[b]
storetext.style.color=rainbow
}
function change(){
if (seq==6){
b--
if (b==0)
seq=1
}
if (seq==5){
r++
if (r==12)
seq=6
}
if (seq==4){
g--
if (g==0)
seq=5
}
if (seq==3){
b++
if (b==12)
seq=4
}
if (seq==2){
r--
if (r==0)
seq=3
}
if (seq==1){
g++
if (g==12)
seq=2
}
changetext()
}
function starteffect(){
if (document.all||document.getElementById)
flash=setInterval("change()",speed)
}
starteffect()
</script>
</b>
```

Comment: The first line is missing quotes around the string. Is that in the real script or a copying error?

Comment: You never use the `el` variable, why are you setting it?

Comment: `document.getElementById()` has been supported since IE 5.5. There's no need to use `document.all` today.

Comment: @Barmar I copied this code off the internet somewhere, I guess `document.all` was still relevant at the time the code was posted. Anyway, yeah the missing quotes was a copying error, sorry, I just fixed it.

Comment: `<marquee>` and `</marquee>` has to be inside the quotes.

Comment: I don't think I actually tried putting the tag in the quotes. I'll try and run the script with quotes around the tag.

Comment: If you didn't put the tag in quotes, you should have gotten a syntax error. Didn't you check the console for errors before posting here?

Comment: No, I don't actually have access to a console at the moment because I am currently using Notepad to write HTML. (not Notepad++)
Anyways, putting quotes around the tag worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: You shouldn't change the question to contain the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... Works here on https://codepen.io/cunlay/pen/jOOmaRv

```
<b>
<script>
var text = "<marquee>hello and welcome to my website</marquee>"; // YOUR TEXT
var speed = 80; // SPEED OF FADE
var r = 1, g = 1, b = 1, seq = 1;
var hex = new Array("00","14","28","3C","50","64","78","8C","A0","B4","C8","DC","F0");
var storetext;

// ********** LEAVE THE NEXT BIT ALONE!
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('marquee')[0];
if (document.all || document.getElementById){
    document.write('<span id="highlight">' + text + '</span>');
}else{
    document.write(text);
}

function changetext(){
    var rainbow = "#"+hex[r]+hex[g]+hex[b];
    storetext = document.getElementById("highlight");
    storetext.style.color = rainbow;
}

function change(){
    if(seq==6){
        b--;
        if(b==0){
            seq=1;
        }       
    }else if (seq==5){
        r++;
        if (r==12){
            seq=6;
        }       
    }else if (seq==4){
        g--;
        if(g==0){
            seq=5;
        }       
    }else if (seq==3){
        b++;
        if (b==12){
            seq=4;
        }       
    }else if (seq==2){
        r--;
        if(r==0){
            seq=3;
        }       
    }else if (seq==1){
        g++;
        if(g==12){
            seq=2;
        }               
    }else {
        return false;
    }   
    changetext();
}
function starteffect(){
    if (document.all || document.getElementById){
        var flash = setInterval("change()",speed);
    }
    return false;
}
starteffect();
</script>
</b>
```